# O que é cada um dos "tipos de dados" do DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

Estou estudando a respeito do [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM) e me surgiu uma dúvida referente aos tipos de dados dele, que são:

- `document`
- `element`
- `nodeList`
- `node`
- `attribute`
- `namedNodeMap`

Eu não compreendi muito o que cada tipo de dado representa no *documento*, portanto eu gostaria de ter minha dúvida esclarecida.

## Dúvida

O que é cada um desses *tipos de dados* listado acima pertencente ao DOM? Para que eles servem?

---

<sup>Se possível, eu gostaria de exemplos em JS ilustrando cada um deles.</sup>

Comment: Não entendi bem por que exatamente esses tipos de dados, o que não falta no DOM é interface. Não está claro aonde você quer chegar, e ao mesmo tempo a pergunta é um pouco ampla. Tentando dar uma situada, o documento (`document`) é feito de nós (*nodes*). Isso inclui os elementos do HTML (cada um sendo um `element` ou subclasse), todo o texto dentro das tags HTML, incluindo os espaços em branco, e os atributos das tags. Portanto `element` e `attribute` são subtipos de `node`. NodeLists o nome já diz, são listas de nós. `namedNodeMap` são conjuntos de atributos.

Comment: @bfavaretto acho melhor editar para "o que é cada tipo" ao invés da "finalidade", eu quis expressar isso.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas é que é uma lista meio arbitrária de tipos. Isso que eu acho estranho na pergunta. Vamos ver se alguém responde detalhando, eu infelizmente estou sem tempo.

Comment: @bfavaretto não entendi o que vc quis dizer com "uma lista meio arbitrária de tipos", o que poderia ser?

Comment: Porque o DOM é composto de [uma lista muito maior de tipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM#DOM_interfaces). Qual é o motivo de você escolher justo esses para perguntar?

Comment: @bfavaretto me parecer ser os mais comuns para aprender de inicio. Mas pode fazer uma pergunta para cada tipo, o que acha?

Comment: Deixa assim, acho que não tem formato ideal neste caso.

Answer (score 1):

Dado o html abaixo vou explicar os conceitos:

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Document Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divPai">
    <h1>Lista exemplo</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 01</li>
      <li>Item 01</li>
      <li>Item 01</li>
      <li>Item 01</li>
      <li>Item 01</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**1. `document`**
O document é um objeto que toda página html tem. É como se existisse uma tag `<document></document>` envolvendo toda a página html pois ele é essencial, e usada para carregar consigo informações importantes da página e de todo seu conteúdo. E para você conseguir acessar algumas propriedades do html você precisa passar por ela. [Veja a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document)

Exemplo: `console.log(document.title)` neste caso vai retornar o "Document Title" que é o conteúdo da tag `title` acima. Você pode exploxar todos os objetos dentro do `document` dando um console.log nele.

**2. `element` e `node`**
Para explicar o `element` vou falar também do `node`. `node` é uma nomenclatura genérica dada à elementos dentro da hierarquia do DOM. O `document`, `document.title` também é um [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node), porém também podem ser elementos como `<h1>`ou um `<input />`. Já `element` é um tipo especifico de `node`, geralmente são os [elementos dentro da tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element) `body` do seu html.

Exemplo: Se você todos os elementos `li` da página basta usar `document.getElementsByTagName('LI')` e esse código vai retornar uma `nodeList` ou `HTMLCollection` com todos os elementos LI dentro.

**3. `nodeList`** A https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList ou [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) é uma lista assim como um [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), porém vale ressaltar que não é um array. Esses dois conceitos carregam uma lista de `element`s que são linkados ao DOM do página, assim, dando a possibilidade de manipular uma lista de elementos de uma vez só

**4. `attribute`** atributos são as propriedades que um `element` tem. Tags `img` irão ter `src`, `<a>` irão ter `href`, `<div>`s poderão ter `class` ou `id` e por ai vai.

Exemplo: Usar `document.getElementById('divPai').attributes` para acessar o elemento div com id `divPai` irá retornar uma `NamedNodeMap`. Porem eu posso acessar diretamente o atributo `id` usando `document.getElementById('divPai').id` neste caso irá retornar "divPai".

**5. `NamedNodeMap`** Na minha opinião é o mais confuso pois é semelhante um array, e também `nodeList` porém tem uma estrutura interna de [objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) mas explicando `NamedNodeMap` apesar de ter Node no nome não tem nada a ver com isso, ele é usando somente para retornar uma lista de `attributes` de um `element`. É isso ele é uma lista. [Veja a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap) deste cara!

No final das contas todos esses conceitos são usados em conjunto para manipular o DOM. Espero ter esclarecido.